# Как учесть число записей в фильтрации Django

Tags: django, django-orm, django-filter

Есть две модели:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Entry(models.Model):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Если нужно получить все записи конкретного автора, то можно делать так:

```
Entry.objects.filter(authors__name= 'Petrov')
```

1. Как получить все записи автора, в которых он единственный автор.
2. Как получить записи, в которых заданное число авторов одновременно.

Answer (score 0):

Первый вопрос

```
from django.db.models import Q, Count
Entry.objects.annotate(users_count=Count('authors')).filter(authors__name= 'Petrov', users_count=1)
```

Второй не понял.